# Cursor Tracking Python Tkinter

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

I am creating a chess and the first problem I have is implementing a creating the code that will allow me to get the current position of the mouse and print that image of the mouse in that mouse coordinates and basically loop it until the user says so. Right now it is just on a timer. Feel free to replace the image with another gif. This is only a partion of the code

I don't know what else to try. I've basically rearranged the code hoping that that was the problem but it wasn't.

```
def Mousecoords():

    pointxy = root.winfo_pointerxy()


    print(str(pointxy))

    canvas.create_image(pointxy[0], pointxy[1], image=whiteKing.pieceImage)
    time.sleep(0.3)


ok = 0


while ok <= 10:
    root.after(500, Mousecoords)
    ok += 1
```

Right now, what the code does is it gets the actual coordinates of the cursor in real time and after it has done so throughout the duration of the timer, it displays the images however, what I am trying to achieve is get the coordinates and the images getting printed out simulatenously.

right now, what it does is:

gets coordinates (1)
gets coordinates (2)
gets coordinates (3)
gets coordinates (4)
gets coordinates (5)
gets coordinates (6)
gets coordinates (7)
gets coordinates (8)
gets coordinates (9)
gets coordinates (10)

prints image (1-10 at the same time)

instead what i want it to do is:

gets coordinates (1)
displays image at (1)
gets coordinates (2)
displays image at (2)
gets coordinates (3)
displays image at (3)
gets coordinates (4)
displays image at (4)
gets coordinates (5)
displays image at (5)
gets coordinates (6)
displays image at (6)
gets coordinates (7)
displays image at (7)
gets coordinates (8)
displays image at (8)
gets coordinates (9)
displays image at (9)
gets coordinates (10)
displays image at (10)

if theres any other way or method of having an image follow the cursor, please enlighten me thank you
Also please tell me if i didn't explain clearly or missed out a few bits

Comment: You don't need to call `sleep()` which will block the tkinter `mainloop()`.  It may be the cause of your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not use `winfo_pointerxy()` as it returns mouse position relative to screen origin (the top-left corner of screen).  Use `bind('<Motion>', callback)` on canvas to track the mouse position relative to canvas (then you don't need to use `.after()`).  Also, you should not recreate the image every time you want to update the image, you should update the coordinate of the image instead.

Below is a sample code:

```
from tkinter import *
from PIL import Image, ImageTk

def Mousecoords(event):
    pointxy = (event.x, event.y) # get the mouse position from event
    print(pointxy)
    canvas.coords(cimg, pointxy) # move the image to mouse postion

root = Tk()
img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(file='_red.png')
canvas = Canvas(width=400, height=200)
cimg = canvas.create_image(200, 100, image=img)
canvas.pack()
canvas.bind('<Motion>', Mousecoords) # track mouse movement
root.mainloop()
```

And the output:

[image]